# livewire inline table edit form stops submitting any request to server when it's hidden and only shown when edit is clicked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am working on an inline component table edit functionality in Laravel livewire the form works fine when its shown as a regular table line but when I try to make it so the user gets the edit row when he clicks on edit the form stops submitting requests when clicking on submit .
When I pull up the network chrome tool it shows that when submit is clicked no request is sent .
This is the blade of the component

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
    <button @click="open = true" class="bg-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-700 text-white font-bold mb-2 py-2 px-4 rounded">
        Add product
    </button>
    <table class="min-w-full table-fixed text-center">
        <!-- This is the table header -->
        <thead class="justify-between">
            <tr class="bg-gray-900">
                <th class="py-2  ">
                    <span class="text-white"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="py-2">
                    <span class="text-white">Name</span>
                </th>
                <th class="py-2 ">
                    <span class="text-white">Quantity</span>
                </th>
                <th class="py-2">
                    <span class="text-white">Price</span>
                </th>
                <th class="py-2 ">
                    <span class="text-white">Fav</span>
                </th>
                <th class=" py-2">
                    <span class="text-white">Action</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-gray-200">
            <!-- this is the ADD form that pops up when you click add product -->
            <form autocomplete="off" wire:submit.prevent="formSubmit" action="" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div>
                    <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 " x-show.transition.duration.500="open" @click.away="open = !open">
                        <td class="px-5 py-2 flex flex-row items-center">
                            <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover " src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/30.jpg" alt="" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" wire:model.defer='name' name="name" class="rounded h-6 w-40 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                        </td>
                        <td class=" py-2">
                            <input type="number" autocomplete="off" wire:model.defer='quantity' name="quantity" class="rounded h-6 w-16 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                        </td>
                        <td class=" py-2">
                            <input type="number" autocomplete="off" wire:model.defer='price' name="price" class="rounded h-6 w-16 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                        </td>
                        <td class=" py-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" class=" h-5 w-5 text-red-300 checked:outline-none " checked>
                        </td>
                        <td class=" content-center">
                            <button @click.debounce.500="open = !open" class="w-20 min-w-20 content-center bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold px-4 rounded">
                                <div wire:loading.remove wire:target="formsubmit">
                                    save
                                </div>
                                <div wire:loading wire:target="formsubmit">
                                    <div class="animate-spin w-3  h-3 max-w-3 max-w-3 p-0 m-0  border-t-2 border-l-2 border-r-2  border-white rounded-full loader"></div>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </form>
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                @if ($product->id == $editedRow)
                    <!-- this is the edit form -->
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="editSubmit" method="POST">
                        <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100" @click.away="$wire.editedRow = null">
                            <td class="px-5 py-2 flex flex-row items-center">
                                <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover " src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/30.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td class=" py-2">
                                <input value="{{$editname}}" wire:model="editname" type="text" class="rounded h-6 w-36 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                            </td>
                            <td class=" py-2">
                                <input value="{{$editquantity}}" wire:model="editquantity" type="text" class="rounded h-6 w-16 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                            </td>
                            <td class=" py-2">
                                <input value="{{$editprice}}" wire:model="editprice" type="text" class="rounded h-6 w-16 border border-gray-900 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-gray-900 ">
                            </td>
                            <td class=" py-2"></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" class="w-20 min-w-20 content-center bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold px-4 rounded">save</button>
                            </td>
                        </form>
                    @else
                        <!-- and finally this is the content of table  -->
                        <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100">
                            <td class="px-5 py-2 flex flex-row items-center">
                                <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover " src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/30.jpg" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="text-center ml-2 font-semibold">{{$product->name}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-16 py-2">
                                <span>{{$product->quantity}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-16 py-2">
                                <span>{{$product->price}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class=" py-2">
                                <button wire:click="changeHeart('{{$product->id}}')" class="h-9 w-9 min-h-8 min-w-8 content-center rounded-md border border-transparent text focus:outline-none {{ $product->favourite ? 'bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400' : 'bg-red-300 hover:bg-red-400' }}">
                                    <svg wire:loading.remove wire:target="changeHeart('{{$product->id}}')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="m-auto text-center content-center h-5 w-5 {{ $product->favourite ? 'text-black' : 'text-white' }} " fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <div wire:loading wire:target="changeHeart('{{$product->id}}')" class="animate-spin w-5 align-middle h-5 max-h-5 max-w-5   border-t-2 border-l-2 border-r-2 {{ $product->favourite ? ' border-black ' : ' border-white' }} rounded-full loader"></div>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-16 py-2">
                                <!-- when you click on this you set the editedRow variable to product id  -->
                                <span class="text-blue-500 inline-block mr-1 cursor-pointer">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" wire:click='editRow({{$product->id}})'>
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11 5H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v11a2 2 0 002 2h11a2 2 0 002-2v-5m-1.414-9.414a2 2 0 112.828 2.828L11.828 15H9v-2.828l8.586-8.586z" />
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text-red-500 inline-block ml-1 cursor-pointer">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 14l2-2m0 0l2-2m-2 2l-2-2m2 2l2 2m7-2a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        <br>
```

And this is the controller of it :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class ProductsTable extends Component {
public $name;
public $quantity;
public $price;
public $editname;
public $editquantity;
public $editprice;
public $editedRow = null;

public function formSubmit() {
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = $this->name;
    $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
    $product->price = $this->price;
    $product->save();
    $this->empty();
}
public function empty() {
    $this->name = '';
    $this->quantity = '';
    $this->price = '';
}

public function editRow($id) {
    $product = Product::findorfail($id);
    $this->editedRow = $id;
    $this->editname = $product->name;
    $this->editquantity = $product->quantity;
    $this->editprice = $product->price;
}
public function editSubmit($id) {
    $product = Product::findorfail($id);
    $product->name = $this->name;
    $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
    $product->price = $this->price;
    $product->save();
    $this->empty();
}
public function render() {
    return view('livewire.products-table', ["products" => DB::table('products')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(9),]);
}
```

}

And as you can see here no request is sent when I click submit: https://imgur.com/oZZimsh
if you need any more info please ask for it I will be checking this post regularly
Thank you for your time.
EDIT : i have solved this , what i did is i dropped the form way and just linked the input with variables in the component's controller with wire:model , although i dont know how safe it is since i didn't use csrf .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the @csrf on the edit form .

and go also on the Model Product make sure the fields , you are trying to fill are fillable , it doesn't stop you from creating but it does for editing !

Comment: thank you for reminding me about this , so i did in fact get it to work by just not using <form> although i dont know how safe is it because i didn't use @csrf i hope you can enlighten about this , i'm going to edit in my solution for if anyone gets this prob

Comment: yes i do the same , i don't use form , in reality you don't need it in livewire , since you are wiring your fields , it s always in sync ! but you need absolutely to do the validation even if you don't use the form . i don't see validation in your code ! at the end you use empty() which is good . you have two ways of doing validation in livewire https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation